# Debian Adding Multiple Source File Location (lib,lib64,include etc.)

Tags: linux, debian

I am trying to install SSH from the source. When I install from the source, I need to install also additional dependencies. I also install the dependencies from the source. For example, I install zlib dependencies like that;

```
cd /tmp
mkdir -p /opt/zlib
mkdir zlib1.23
cd zlib1.23/
wget http://www.zlib.net/zlib123.zip
unzip zlib123.zip
make
make install prefix=/opt/zlib/
```

The important system files such as; "include, lib, lib64" comes under my installation location (/opt/zlib/); **"/opt/package"**,

```
/opt/zlib
├── include
│   ├── zconf.h
│   └── zlib.h
├── lib
│   ├── libz.a
│   ├── libz.so -> libz.so.1.3
│   ├── libz.so.1 -> libz.so.1.3
│   ├── libz.so.1.3
│   └── pkgconfig
│       └── zlib.pc
└── share
    └── man
        └── man3
            └── zlib.3
```

When I install this dependency, I also want to ensure that another package with this dependency is searched for "include,lib,lib64" in this location. For example, when another package wants to search for the "zlib" library, I want it to search under the name "/opt/zlib/lib", not "/usr/lib", or from places containing the "include" folder under the "/opt" directory.

Briefly, the question I want to ask is this: When I install a package, I see the **"bin,lib,lib64,include etc."** that comes with installing the package. What can I do so that my files are recognized in the system by default?